# Autoscroll to dynamic content

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-templates, autoscroll

So i am using jquery.tmpl.js template to layout my page. The data to be shown can change each time the page is loaded.

What i want to do is to auto scroll to a div inside of a template. Now i understand that if multiple divs have the same name then it will only scroll to the first one. So i am careful to ensure the templates have different id.

I have attempted to use the `jquery.scrollintoview`, `${idvalue}.focus()`, `${#idvalue}.focus()` with no success. I assume it is because the templates are added after the scripts are fired.

Edit:
so i have no idea how jfiddle working, and i cant get the tmpl working on there. 
but here is the basic of my code:

html:
`<div id="contentStuff"></div>`

javascript:

`<script defer>
    $(window).load(function () {
    $.template("template", $("#template"));
    var item1 = [];
    item1.name = "ted";
    var contentDiv = $('#contentStuff');
    $('#template').tmpl([item1]).appendTo(contentDiv);
    // focus stuff here
}); < /script>`

`<script id="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div id="Test ">
        <p> $(name)</p>
    </div>
</script>`

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: provide us a fiddle..

Comment: I have never used jfiddle before myself, not much of a webdev, but i have added the basics of my page

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JCVnY/18/ use this and put your code there. Then update it, provide us the new url

Comment: I attempted to, but the output was garbage